# Preg_replace for price string (PHP)

Tags: php, regex

Trying to convert a string with some price "2 200,00" (without quotes) to look like 2200.

```
$result = preg_replace("/([^0-9,]s)/iu","", $result);
```

Doesn't work. Could sombody help, pls?

Comment: Do you want to remove the fraction part also if its `00` or only the whitespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
$result = preg_replace("/[,\s+]/iu","", $result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Whats the `s` good for? And the brackets are also not needed. Try

```
$result = preg_replace("/[^0-9,]+/iu","", $result);
```

Probably better to watch only for whitspaces

```
$result = preg_replace("/\w+/iu","", $result);
```

`+` means match one ore more, i.e. if there is more than one whitespace it would be matched at once.

Comment: the comma is not needed if you have negated numeric class :)

Comment: @Tudor he has a comma in his number and don't want to have it replaced, so I need it in my character class.

Comment: its not just the comma replaced, but everything after the comma also (2 200,00 becomes 2200)

Comment: @stema - Actually, he doesn't want the comma nor the decimals. According to the question, he wants "2 200,00" to become "2200".

Comment: $result = preg_replace("/[^0-9,]+/iu","", $result);
This adds  additional zeroes to the price. Original string "2 200,00", after preg_preplace i get this "220000". Should be "2200"

Comment: @Zhlobopotam no it shouldn't. It keeps the fraction part. The result should look like 2200,00

Answer (score 1):

http://www.crainbandy.com/programming/function-to-remove-all-non-numeric-characters-in-php

Comment: The solution in your link replaces all non numeric using `\D`, that means it will also replace the comma in his example and giving him then a wrong number.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `intval` and `str_replace` instead of `preg_replace`.

```
// Results in 2200 (without decimals)
$result = intval(str_replace(' ', '', $result));
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex is not required for this.

```
$number = '2 200,00';
echo str_replace(array(' ', ','), '', substr($number, 0, strrpos($number, ',')));
```

(If the number string *always* contains a comma)